# Database Sanitize Check owner

Tags: php, mysql

This is code for Delete link:

```
<a href="picture_manager.php?do=delete&id=<?php print $picturedata['id']; ?>" >Delete</a>
```

This is my current database syntax:

```
if (array_key_exists('do', $_GET) && $_GET['do'] == "delete" && array_key_exists('id', $_GET))
{
    $pictureid = trim(sanitize($_GET['id']));

    if ($picture->delete($pictureid) === true)
    {
        header('Location: picture_manager.php?success=removed');
    }
}
```

With code above, other user can delete others user picture like = picture_manager.php?do=delete&id=(victim).

Now I found solution to prevent abuse by other user, I change the old syntax as below:

This is my new database syntax:

```
if (!array_key_exists('id', $_GET) || $_GET['id'] == "" || $picture->pictureExists(trim(sanitize($_GET['id']))) === false || $picture->checkOwn($user->getUserID(trim(sanitize($_SESSION['key']))), trim(sanitize($_GET['id']))) === false)
{
    header('Location: picture_manager.php');
}
else    
{
    $pictureid = trim(sanitize($_GET['id']));

    if ($picture->delete($pictureid) === true)
    {
        header('Location: picture_manager.php?success=removed');
    }
}
```

Sadly, it did not work "The page isn't redirecting properly - said firefox browser"

Looking for expert right now.

I found solution in below answer.

**NOW EDIT**:
Its difficult to me when I coded as below:

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'delete' && (!array_key_exists('id', $_GET) || $_GET['id'] == "" || $picture->pictureExists(trim(sanitize($_GET['id']))) === false || $picture->checkOwn($user->getUserID(trim(sanitize($_SESSION['key']))), trim(sanitize($_GET['id']))) === false))
{
    header('Location: picture_manager.php');
}
else    
{
    $pictureid = trim(sanitize($_GET['id']));

    if ($picture->delete($pictureid) === true)
    {
        header('Location: picture_manager.php?success=removed');
    }
}
```

The file doesn't delete when I click i.e picture_manager.php?do=delete&id=6125

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Looking for solution right now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

infinite redirect, !array_key_exists('id', $_GET) will proceed always. you need add ?do=delete to validation, like

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'delete' && (!array_key_exists('id', $_GET) || $_GET['id'] == "" || $picture->pictureExists(trim(sanitize($_GET['id']))) === false || $picture->checkOwn($user->getUserID(trim(sanitize($_SESSION['key']))), trim(sanitize($_GET['id']))) === false))
```

Comment: you need to add to else the same checker, just using else if (). or add if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'delete') { ... } in front of all part of code

Comment: http://notepad.cc/laiviqa75 this will trigger your code only when it's ?do=delete